Can we show Lightning Email popup from a custom button?
In Classic the standard Salesforce email screen can be referenced using this URL "/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor" and passing parameters - doc_id, p2_lkid, p3_lkid, etc.
I was wondering if there is something similar in Lightning to reference the Email popup and pass the parameters?
The use case - there is business logic to generate the documents, recipients, and email subject and body dynamically. Once those are identified, they need to be passed as parameters to the email popup.

Yes, there is an official API for this, documented in Create an Email as a Quick Action (LWC) and Create an Email as a Quick Action (Aura). Basically, you use lightning:navigation/lightning-navigation to open the quick action, along with any defaultFieldValues that you'd like to set. Please check out the documentation for all the details. You can also just create a standard Quick Action that offers a no-code solution, and you can provide some limited default values (not as flexible as code, but better than nothing).

thank you @sfdcfox as usual for the prompt and accurate info. However, it seems there are some limitations with the QuickAction - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.case_interaction_send_email_quick_action_considerations.htm&type=5

Customer community users in Experience Cloud sites can't send emails.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000OsRorSAF

Not able to attach a PDF/ContentDocumentId. This is a must have


@MiteshSura See Send Emails to Leads and Contacts from an Experience Cloud Site if that helps. Not sure if that can get you all the way there, though. Digital Experiences have significant limitations.

Thanks again, not sure if we will be able to proceed with this. The road block is not able to attach the document programmatically as mentioned in this thread - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000OsRorSAF
